# How to replicate the scenario of the snippet attached below of Postman with Java Spring boot to send a .cer and .key file

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

.cer file is an X.509 format certificate and .key is a RSA key that is required to get the data from the client I want to replicate the scenario in spring boot java plz find the snippet attched below of Postman
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if the answer will fit perfectly. In my case I had an X.509 certificate in pem format provided by the server and an RSA key. They were required when making REST calls. What I had to do is load the certificate and key into keystore and then create SSLContext. This SSLContext was then bound to the HttpsURLConnection

```
public SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    try {
        //== Setting certificate format to X509 and converting bytes to certificate object
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        //== Reading the certificate provided by FDMS API using above format
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(certsfolder + "server-certificate.pem"));

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(new FileInputStream(certsfolder + "privkey.pem").readAllBytes());
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        //== Reading the private key of the client i.e. machine running this code
        //== Private key also used in generating certificate by FMDS API
        //== Converting key bytes to string for processing
        String privateKeyPEM = new String(new FileInputStream(certsfolder + "privkey.pem").readAllBytes())
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        //== Decoding key string to base64
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
        //== Turning decoded string to PrivateKey object
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        PrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        //== Load the certificate and private key into a keystore
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(null, null); // Initialize an empty keystore
        keystore.setCertificateEntry("zimra.co.zw", cert);
        //== Important that it has a certificate chain
        keystore.setKeyEntry("cottco-1-0000010605", key, "".toCharArray(), new X509Certificate[]{cert});

        //== Create SSL context with the keystore
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, "".toCharArray()) // Use an empty password
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, (chain, authType) -> true) // Trust all certificates
                .build();
        return sslContext;
    } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (CertificateException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InvoiceLocalServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The above created the SSLContext. Then to bind it:

```
//== Calling method to generate SSL Context for use in TLS Handshake
        SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();

        //== Adding SSL Context to HttpsURLConnection calls
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```